# Unable to get static image, Tomcat 8.0.24

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have an application with the back-end that is implemented using Spring MVC and front end - AngularJs.

I would like to display uploaded images at my front end. The most simple way, as far as I googled it out, is to edit the `server.xml`at the folder `apache-tomcat-8.0.24\conf` by adding the following line:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      <Context docBase="C:\images_test" path="/my_project/images"> <-- this line was added by me. 
      </Context>
  </Host>
```

After it, I could simply access the image by the following URI: `http://localhost:8080/my_project/images/pic.jpg`

However, I cannot do it. The browser displays me 404 error status. How can I access this picture from my browser and possibly from `<img>`?

Should I redeploy the application to the Tomcat server or should I restart the server after modifying the server.xml filE?

Comment: Did you tried http://localhost:8080/my_project/images/pic.jpg ?

Comment: It is a typo. I was accessing my picture via the following path: http://localhost:8080/my_project/images/pic.jpg

Comment: what's your file structure in C:\images_test ? path="/my_project/images" means your context-path, in this case I think you should set it to "/"

Comment: the structure is the following: C:\images_test\pic1.jpg, C:\images_test\pic2.jpg and so on.

Comment: As per your question you can access it with "http://localhost:8080/my_project/images/pic.jpg" but you written "However, I cannot do it.". So can you edit your question which URL actually you are not able to open?

Comment: It is my memory flawed, but try  "C:/images_test" - and file names must be case-sensitive of course.

Answer (score 0):

If Tomcat is for example installed on C: then the /path/to/files would actually point to C:\path\to\files. Thus below should be in your code.

```
<Context docBase="/images_test" path="/my_project/images">
```

Above docbase would point to `C:\images_test`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work for you :

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="C:\path_to_project" path="/my_project" aliases="/images=C:\images_test">
    </Context>
</Host>
```

Then, just try something like http://localhost:8080/my_project/images/pic1.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="C:\images_test" path="" />
</Host>
```

and you should be able to access your image via http://localhost:port/pic1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in my IDE - Intellij IDEA, it creates a custom server.xml for each web application.